# Flex builder 3 or Flash builder 4?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

Mainly my project was to create some UI interaction. Degrafa supported Flex 3 and FXG supported Flex 4. Which would you choose in term of performance in UI and AIR 2.0?

Comment: Your subject line is asking about IDEs, while your question asks about frameworks.  What information are you trying to get?  Are you talking about runtime performance of respective approaches in the Flex Framework?  OR are you talking about development performance in the IDE?

Comment: Oh, to be clearer, I use both IDE, but my question was about creating UI interaction with either Degrafa or FXG.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are talking about the Framework/SDK's as opposed to the IDE's.

I'd highly recommend Flex4 over Flex3, building UI's that are highly customized is many times easier than with Flex3 thanks to the addition of the Spark component framework.

Performance wise, the Flex4 framework is also generally improved over Flex3.

Comment: Ok, I will now migrate to Flash 4 SDK.